# How to add an index that increments on groups of rows of text not including NaT

Tags: pandas, increment

I have a data frame that has a column of codes that has consecutive rows of text followed by consecutive rows of null values (NaN).

```
  codes
  FKW
  FCJ
  XQ8
  1L9
  NaN
  NaN
  PNU
  LIT
  NaN
  422
```

The group of alphnumeric codes and missing values (NaN) form a cycle.I want to add an column of cycle indices (index) that is increment when the next cycle starts.  The next cycle starts when a missing value (NaN) is followed by a code (alphanumeric value).

```
code    index
FKW     1
FCJ     1
XQ8     1
1L9     1
NaN     1
NaN     1
PNU     2   next group starts here
LIT     2
NaN     2
422     3   next group starts here
```

Here is code to generate the above examples

```py
    def id_generator(size=3, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))    
    num_rows = 10
    data = np.array([id_generator() for i in range(num_rows)])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['code'])
    df.code[4,5,8]=NaN
    print('what i have')
    print(df)
    print('what I want')
    df['index']=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]
    print(df)
```

How can I generate the index column?

Comment: What is the logic for generating the index? That the number runs till the NaT & then the number change when NaT turns to something else?

Comment: The data has rows of codes followed by rows of missing codes (NaN).  A cycle is the group of codes and group of missing codes (NaN).  A new cycle starts when a code is preceeded by a missing code (NaN).  The actual data also has time values, which contains NaT instead of NaN.  I mixed up NaN and NaT when writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is iterating over the contents of your dataframe and keeping track of if the last value was NaN.

```py
index = []
index_counter = 1
last_was_NaN = False
for row in df.itertuples():
    if type(row[1]) is float and np.isnan(row[1]):  # check if second column (first after pandas indices) is NaN
        last_was_NaN = True
    elif last_was_NaN:  # if we have text now, we can store that and increase the counter
        last_was_NaN = False
        index_counter += 1
    index.append(index_counter)  # don't forget to add the calculated index
df['index'] = index
```

Comment: Last week I did something similar using iterrows on a sample data set.  But the problem is the data has millions of rows, and I was wonder if there's a faster way.  Let me check the run time of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = df.codes.notna()
df['index'] = (s & ~(s.shift(fill_value=False))).cumsum()

Out[718]:
  codes  index
0   FKW      1
1   FCJ      1
2   XQ8      1
3   1L9      1
4   NaN      1
5   NaN      1
6   PNU      2
7   LIT      2
8   NaN      2
9   422      3
```